# How to merge multiple Json files in folder in certain order

Tags: json, merge, jq

I have several JSON files in a folder and I want to combine them in a single one following certain order given in `order.json`

I´ve tested the code below that merges all the files but in alphabetical order based on file name.

```
jq -s . *.json > Merged.json
```

This is the file **Shoes.json**

```
{ "document": { "product": "Shoes", "info": [ { "day": "1", "month": "1", "entry": "Some text about Shoes for day 1 and month 1", "code": "AJKD" }, { "day": "2", "month": "1", "entry": "Some text about Shoes for day 2 and month 1", "code": "KKGIR" } ] } }
```

This is the file **Watches.json**

```
{ "document": { "product": "Watches",   "info": [ { "day": "2", "month": "3",   "entry": "Some text about Watches for day 2 and month 3",   "code": "PEWQ" }    ] }     }
```

This is the file **Accesories.json**

```
{ "document": { "product": "Accesories",    "info": [ { "day": "7", "month": "2",   "entry": "Some text about Accesories for day 7 and month 2",    "code": "UYAAC" }   ] }     }
```

This is the file that gives the order I want to get in output **order.json**

```
{  
   "order":{  
      "product 1":"Watches",
      "product 2":"Accesories",
      "product 3":"Shoes"
   }
}
```

And the output file I´d like to get would be like this **Merged.json**:

```
{  
   "document":[  
      {  
         "product":"Watches",
         "info":[  
            {  
               "day":"2",
               "month":"3",
               "entry":"Some text about Watches for day 2 and month 3",
               "code":"PEWQ"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "product":"Accesories",
         "info":[  
            {  
               "day":"7",
               "month":"2",
               "entry":"Some text about Accesories for day 7 and month 2",
               "code":"UYAAC"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "product":"Shoes",
         "info":[  
            {  
               "day":"1",
               "month":"1",
               "entry":"Some text about Shoes for day 1 and month 1",
               "code":"AJKD"
            },
            {  
               "day":"2",
               "month":"1",
               "entry":"Some text about Shoes for day 2 and month 1",
               "code":"KKGIR"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Maybe someone could help me with this case.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses order.json to determine which files are to be read by jq:

```
jq -n '{documents: [inputs.document]}' $(jq -r '.order[] + ".json"' order.json)
```

The approach exemplified immediately above has many advantages, but the above line makes various assumptions that might not be warranted.  For example, it assumes there are no spaces in any of the file names.

### Robust handling of file names

The following assumes bash-ful functionality:

```
mapfile -t args < <(jq -r '.order[] + ".json"' order.json)
jq -n '{documents: [inputs.document]}' "${args[@]}"
```

If your bash does not have `mapfile`, you could set the bash variable as follows:

```
args=()
while read -r f; do 
  args+=("$f")
done < <(jq -r '.order[] + ".json"' order.json)
```

Comment: I´m not the expert at all, but this second solution looks even better for me and shorter and easiest to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

The following solution has the advantage of not requiring any shell-specific functionality and only requiring a single invocation of jq. It assumes you want to be able to handle arbitrarily many files, as determined by `order.json`.  Amongst other assumptions is that in the pwd, we can use the pattern `[A-Z]*.json` to select the relevant "documents".

```
jq -n --argfile order order.json '
  INDEX(inputs.document;  .product) as $dict
  | reduce $order.order[] as $product ([]; . + [$dict[$product]])
  | {document: .}
' [A-Z]*.json
```

#### def INDEX

If your jq does not have `INDEX/2`, then it might be a good time to upgrade; alternatively, you could simply add (prepend) its def:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({}; .[$row|idx_expr|tostring] = $row);
```

Comment: Hi again peak. Thanks for your help. I've tried with the same files I posted in question but I get this error `jq: error: INDEX/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 2:
  INDEX(inputs.document;  .product) as $dict
jq: 1 compile error`. jq version it says `[version 1.5-1-a5b5cbe]` if it matters.

Comment: Definitely I´ll need to upgrade. But meantime I tested your code adding the INDEX function and it works perfect. If you have a chance, since this solution is smaller, may you explain the logic please. What each step does? Thanks again.

Comment: You can read up on INDEX and reduce in the standard jq documentation.  You might find it helpful to use https://jqplay.org to consolidate your understanding. If you are unfamiliar with the concept of "reduction", you might find this blog post helpful --  http://blog.differentpla.net/blog/2019/01/11/jq-reduce/ -- but note that the first section contains an error.  As an exercise, you might like to try to find it.